# Can I shoot tethered with a Fujifilm hs20?

Tags: tethering, fujifilm

I have a FUJI HS20 and I'd like to know if it's possible to take photos with the camera using a computer/laptop. Or if I can take photos and get them directly to the computer without using import "routine"!

In other words, if it's possible to connect the HS20 to a PC/laptop and be able to take the shots by pressing a key on my computer keyboard; Or shoot the photos by pressing camera's key and see it on the computer's monitor.

Is there a certain device/interface necessary? Or there is a required software?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Fuji Finepix HS20 does not offer that functionality itself.

However, you can use a [Toshiba FlashAir SDHC](http://www.toshiba-components.com/FlashAir/) card which is a WiFi access point. All you need it to use the shutter to take shots and use the computer to browse the card. You will see your images as they get shot.

Alternately, you can get an [EyeFi](http://www.eye.fi/) card which is more complicated to setup because it has to connect to your computer, rather than the other way around.